# Python: how convert string to list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a lot of strings, that were lists before writing to the csv.
And now it looks like

```
s = "['SOAR', 'SIEM', 'SOAR']"
```

How can I convert it into list?

```
out = ['SOAR', 'SIEM', 'SOAR']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)